# How can i pass values from view controller class to objective c class with UIView as subclass in iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview

I want to pass values(inputs from user)from view controller class to objective c class with UIView as subclass.And in objective c class I want to draw using these inputs. how an I do it?
Please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is an `int`, `float`, `BOOL`, `NSString`, `NSData` or `NSDate`, then the easiest thing to do is to store these values in `NSUserDefaults`. They can then be recalled any time you wish from any `UIViewController`.

The [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has all the information to get you started. In addition to the wealth of information there, here's a simple example of how to save and retrieve an `NSString`:

```
-(void)saveToUserDefaults:(NSString*)myString
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"Prefs"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }
}

-(NSString*)retrieveFromUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *val = nil;

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
        val = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Prefs"];

    return val;
}
```